# how to install scmtools on linux machine?

Tags: linux, version-control, rtc

I wanted to install **SCM Tools** on **linux machine**(**RED HAT 5**) without any eclipse IDE.

The following are the steps I followed:

1. I didn't install eclipse on this machine?
2. Installed the Java 1.6 version on the linux machine.
3. Set the JAVA_HOME
4. Installed SCM Tools related to RTC version 4.0.4.

When I was trying to use scm commands an error was thrown:

Unrecognized option: -Xdump:system:events=systhrow,filter=java/lang/OutOfMemoryE                                                                             rror,request=exclusive+prepwalk

**Could not create the Java virtual machine**.

Scm:
JVM terminated
Exit code=1

/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.37.x86_64/jre/bin/java
-Xmx512m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xdump:system:events=systhrow,filter=java/lang/OutOfMemoryError,request=exclusiv                                                                             e+prepwalk
-jar /install/RTC/jazz/scmtools/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.                                                                             1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /install/RTC/jazz/scmtools/eclipse/scm
-name Scm
--launcher.library /install/RTC/jazz/scmtools/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equin                                                                             ox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101019_1345/eclipse_1310.so
-startup /install/RTC/jazz/scmtools/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launche                                                                             r_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
-exitdata 728010
-data @noDefault
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.37.x86_64/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xmx512m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xdump:system:events=systhrow,filter=java/lang/OutOfMemoryError,request=exclusiv                                                                             e+prepwalk
-jar /install/RTC/jazz/scmtools/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.                                                                             1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar

I have tried also enabling some lines in SCM.ini also but it also didn't work(-vm  .../../jdk/jre/bin)

1. How to solve this issue?
2. Did I miss any configurations?
3. Is it mandatory to install eclipse on linux machine?

Thanks and Regards, 
Vijay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/94641/rtc-scmtools-linux64-4001-installation):

> The Java virtual machine that you are using is not the IBM one.
>
> You will need to remove any `-Xquickstart` and `-Xshareclass*` options from the `lscm`, `scm.sh` and `scm.ini` files.